# Can't get button to center a div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you press on the carousel img you'll notice that it will move itself to center onto the viewport. However, I also want it also happen when you press `.owl-thumb-items` (the numbered button). I tried adding the thumb class to the script like so: `$('.owl-carousel, .owl-thumb-item')`. But it clearly didn't work.

```
$('.owl-carousel, .owl-thumb-item').on('click', function(e) { 

  var el = $(".lazyOwl", this);
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  }
  else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }
  var speed = 700;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:offset}, speed);
});

var animations = new Array();
// queue all
$(".owl-thumb-item").each(function() {
  animations.push($(this));
});

// start animating
doAnimation(animations.shift());

function doAnimation(image) {
  image.fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // wait until animation is done and recurse if there are more animations
    if (animations.length > 0) doAnimation(animations.shift());
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/660/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the buttons, your script would be looking for an element with a class of "lazyOwl" within the button itself. Here's the fix, which just references the "lazyOwl" from the carousel:

```js
var el = $('.owl-carousel .lazyOwl');
$('.owl-carousel, .owl-thumb-item').on('click', function(e) { 

  //  var el = $(".lazyOwl", this);
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tschettler/8bJUc/661/)

Comment: I just noticed that if you click on any of the carousels after the first one, it will scroll back and center to the first carousel and not the currently active one. Please try on (imdarrien.com).

Comment: With multiple items, the above code won't work. Your selector will need to be for a parent that is common between both the carousel and the thumbs, and then from there find the specific lazyOwl element you are looking for. Looking at your site, you have div#two through div#five, but no div#1. If you add the div#1, you could add a common class like 'owlWrapper' between all of these divs and then use the following for finding the owl, within the click handler: var el = $('.lazyOwl', $(this).closest('div.owlWrapper'));